# How do I make my VB.NET program run in MS DOS environment?

Tags: vb.net, dos, environment

So if I made a VB.NET normal windows.form application and then booted into ms dos mode, i am able to run notepad and taskmgr but any normal exe file will just give me an error saying it can't be run in MS DOS mode. Is there a way I can make it compatible with MS DOS environment?

Comment: can you provide your code?? Show us what have you tried

Comment: MS DOS is not a graphical environment.  the error msg was not lying to you.

Comment: Define "MS DOS mode". Are you running the actual DOS operating system?

Comment: Select Console project

Comment: Visual Basic 1.0 for MS-DOS was the last version of Microsoft BASIC that supported MS-DOS. You probably pretty much have to completely rewrite your code for it work with that, though it does at least support "GUI" applications using text mode.

Comment: Why would you expect a WIndows-based WinForms application to run in MS-DOS mode? Doesn't the **WinForms** give you enough information to know that it requires **Windows**, because there's no such things as *DOSForms*? What part of DOS would you expect to support **WinForms**, which is short for **Windows Forms**?

Comment: the first thing to do is to type a VER command at the DOS prompt and tell us what it says

Answer (score 1):

If by "MS-DOS " you mean "command Line" then you can mark your Project as a "Console Application" when you create it in visual studio.  This should enable it to run in the command line.

If by "MS-DOS" you mean the 20 year old operating system by Microsoft, it cant be done.

Comment: *Boot to DOS Mode* means *booting to MS-DOS*.